# Xfce — Metacity window manager — how to change theme?

Tags: xfce, window-management, metacity, xfwm4

In Xfce we can change the window manager in Desktop Settings from Xfwm4 to Metacity.

[image]

But then **the system GTK theme is not followed**, because Metacity has its own theming settings. **That system theme includes a metacity folder**.

I expected that setting to be accessible with `gsettings`/Dconf, but it is not followed, and is marked as deprecated.

[image]

**How to set the Metacity window theme in Xfce?**

---

```
metacity 3.28.0
Xfce 4.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/785241/925128) answer.

In dconf, when something is deprecated the same setting is usually present somewhere else.

It's under `org.gnome.metacity.theme`. Enter theme under `name` and select `metacity` under `type`.

[image]

Or in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity.theme type metacity
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity.theme name THEME_NAME
```

(In older versions of Metacity, the theme could be set with `gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme THEME_NAME`, but that changed with version 3.20.)